# How to create the Count tags name with sequential numbers using ansible script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I create 2 windows **aws** machine using **exact_count** tag as 2.

It creates the both of  2 AWS machine with same name.

For example:

1) itg-Web-windows

2) itg-web-windows

I want to create the machine Name as **instance_tags**:

1)itg-windows-web-1

2)itg-windows-web-2

Below are my code:

```
name: ensure instances are running
        ec2:
          region: "{{ region }}"
          image: "{{ image_id }}"
          group_id: sg-1234
          vpc_subnet_id: subnet-5678
          instance_tags:
             Name: "itg-windows-web"
          exact_count: 2
          count_tag:
             Name: "itg-windows-web"`
          register: ec2_result
```

Comment: Please use correct syntax highlighting for code snippets: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2):

This will create servers with name tags web_server_1, web_server_3 and web_server_5:

```
- name: create instances
  ec2:
    - image: <your_ami>
      instance_type: t2.micro
      key_name: <your_ssh_key>
      region: us-east-1
      vpc_subnet_id: <your_subnet_id>
      count_tag:
        Name: "web_server_{{ item }}"
      exact_count: 1
      instance_tags: 
        Name: "web_server_{{ item }}"
  with_items: ['1', '3', '5']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below ansible template:

```
---
- name: A sample template
  hosts: local
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: create instance
      ec2:
        keypair: test-ssh-key
        instance_type: t2.micro
        image: ami-abcd1234
        wait: yes
        instance_tags:
            ec2type: web
        exact_count: "{{ count }}"
        count_tag:
            ec2type: web
        region: us-east-1
        vpc_subnet_id: subnet-1234abcd
      register: ec2

    - name: generate sequence id for tagging
      debug: msg="{{ item }}"
      no_log: true
      with_sequence: start="{{ startindex }}" end="{{ count }}" format=%02d
      register: sequence

    - name: tag instances
      no_log: true
      ec2_tag:
        region: us-east-1
        resource: "{{ item.0.id }}"
        tags:
            Name: "itg-windows-web-{{ item.1.msg }}"
      with_together:
        - "{{ ec2.instances }}"
        - "{{ sequence.results }}"
```

**command:**

> ansible-playbook -i ./hosts ec2-basic.yml --extra-vars "startindex=1 
>   count=2"

*Invocation-1:*

```
ansible-playbook -i ./hosts ec2-basic.yml --extra-vars "startindex=1  count=2"
```

This will create 2 instances and attach name tag `itg-windows-web-01` and `itg-windows-web-02` to it.

*Invocation 2:*

```
ansible-playbook -i ./hosts ec2-basic.yml --extra-vars "startindex=3  count=4"
```

This will add 2 more instances and attach name tag `itg-windows-web-03` and `itg-windows-web-04` to it.

All these instances are grouped by `ec2type` tag.

**How it works:**

Use a custom tag other than `Name` tag for attribute `count_tag`. If you use `Name` tag, then the same tag-value is assigned for all the instances that are created(which defeats your purpose). In the above script, I have used `ec2type: web` as my *instance_tags* and *count_tag*. So ansible will use this tag to determine how many nodes should run based on the specific tag criteria.

The `count` value which you pass is assigned to `exact_count` in the template. Also you can have further control by passing `startindex` which controls the start of sequence.

*with_sequence* generates a sequence based on your input. [Click here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-integer-sequences) to read more about it.

*with_together* loops over parallel set of data. [Click here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-parallel-sets-of-data) to read more about it.

Using the above ansible loops, we append 01, 02 ... and so on to `itg-windows-web` text and add it to the instance `Name` tag.

Comment: I changed the code as per your sample. I get this below error             fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! unknown error parsing with_sequence arguments: u'start= \"1\" end= \"2\" format=%02d'. Error was: ERROR! can't parse arg start=u'' as integer"}

Comment: That is strange. I have executed the same script successfully. I am using ansible version `2.2.2.0`. Check your version. Also looks like there is a unicode string `u'start=`. It should be just `start=`. have you added `single-quote` before `start=`?

Comment: - name: generate sequence id for tagging
  debug: msg= "{{ item }}"
  no_log: true
  with_sequence: start = "{{startindex}}" end = "{{count}}" format = %02d
  register: sequence

Comment: with_sequence: start="{{startindex}}" end="{{count}}" format=%02d after removing spaces between = the above resolved. But I get  this message now fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! with_together requires at least one element in each list"}

Comment: Below is the code - name: tag instances
  no_log: true
  ec2_tag:
     region: "{{ region }}"
     resource: "{{ item.0.id }}"
     tags:
       Name: "itg-windows-web-{{ item.1.msg }}"
  with_together:
   - "{{ ec2_result.instances }}"
   - "{{ sequence.results }}"

Comment: [DEPRECATION WARNING]: Skipping task due to undefined attribute, in the future this will be a fatal error.. This feature will be removed in a future release. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by
 setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! with_together requires at least one element in each list"}

Comment: You have used `"{{ ec2_result.instances }}"` and `"{{ sequence.results }}"`. Have you added `register: ec2_result` and `register: sequence` in the tasks defined before that? Either one of those list is returning empty. Remove `no_log: true` statement and check If the sequences are generating values in the output.

Comment: - name: ensure instances are running
  with_items: "{{ vpc_subnet }}"
  ec2:
    region: "{{ region }}"
    image: "{{ image_id }}"
    instance_type: "{{ ec2_instance_type }}"
    group_id: sg-133336a
    vpc_subnet_id: subnet-67f9
      wait: yes
    wait_timeout: 500
    instance_tags:
      ec2type: web
    exact_count: 2
    count_tag:
      ec2type: web
  register: ec2_result

Comment: - name: generate sequence id for tagging
  debug: msg= "{{ item }}"
  no_log: true
  with_sequence: start="{{startindex}}" end="{{count}}" format=%02d
  register: sequence

Comment: - name: tag instances
  no_log: true
  ec2_tag:
     region: "{{ region }}"
     resource: "{{ item.0.id }}"
     tags:
       Name: "itg-windows-web-{{ item.1.msg }}"
  with_together:
   - "{{ ec2_result.instances }}"
   - "{{ sequence.results }}"

Comment: Above are my code samples. Even I changed Item.1.id and only item .But list is empty

Comment: Debugging info:

Comment: TASK [infrastructure : generate sequence id for tagging] ***********************
task path: /home/ubuntu/lmm-ansible-windows-aws/roles/infrastructure/tasks/provision-with-vpc1.yml:86
ok: [localhost] => (item=01) => {
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "msg": ""
        },
        "module_name": "debug"
    },
    "item": "01",
    "msg": ""
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=02) => {
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "msg": ""
        },
        "module_name": "debug"
    },
    "item": "02",
    "msg": ""
}

Comment: ok: [localhost] => {
    "sequence": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "msg": ""
                    },
                    "module_name": "debug"
                },
                "item": "01",
                "msg": ""
            }

Comment: {
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "msg": ""
                    },
                    "module_name": "debug"
                },
                "item": "02",
                "msg": ""
            }
        ]

Comment: ec2 item also null only tagged instances tag has values

Comment: "item": null,
                "tagged_instances": [
                    {
                        "ami_launch_index": "0",
                        "architecture": "x86_64",
                        "dns_name": "",
                        "ebs_optimized": false,
                        "groups": {
                            "sg-13d5c16a": "web_server_sg"
                        },
                        "hypervisor": "xen",
                        "id": "i-089ccd54859d8d0e",

Comment: It is difficult to analyze you logs without formatting. DO add some formatting when you comment. I noticed that the sequence is not generating correctly. Instead of `"item": "01", "msg": ""` ,the output should be`"item": "01", "msg": "01"`. Also not sure why you added `with_items: "{{ vpc_subnet }}"` when you are already providing `vpc_subnet_id` with a value. I suggest you to remove `with_items "{{ vpc_subnet }}"` and try. Since you are deviating from the code I suggested in the solution, it will be easier to help if you update the new *script* and *output* as a new section in question itself

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157446/discussion-between-madhukar-mohanraju-and-edwinkamal).

Comment: @MadhukarMohanraju I have tried your code , and this is the error I get ````{"failed": true, "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/playbooks/platform_instance_provision.yml': line 44, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n      register: sequence\n    - name: \"tag ec2 instances\"\n      ^ here\n\nexception type: <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable'>\nexception: 'item' is undefined"} ````